# En se qui concerne/en ce qui concerne

Tags: grammaire

Which one is correct? I think that grammatically correct should be "en ce qui", but I've been seeing "en se qui" a lot so I'm not sure. Why are there two versions and which one is right?

Comment: You are right, "*en ce qui*" is correct, and "*en se qui" is plainly a mistake. It's not a very uncommon one, but usually when you see a "se/ce" mistake in writing (by natives!), you can expect upwards of one orthographical error per word in the neighbourhood. Read with caution if you're a learner ;)

Comment: Yeah, thank you. I thought that was the case :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct form is "en ***ce*** qui concerne".

"*Se*" is a pronoun (of the 3rd person), and is only ever used with pronominal verbs (do something (to) oneself - *se promener, se laver*, etc.). Aside from these, all grammatical constructions use "ce".

Comment: You say “Se … is only...used w/pronominal verbs,” but it's also found in isolated pronominal uses of non-pronominal verbs, no? I mention this nuance not to question your claim, but it might affect Aurélien's claim that "the verb...se concerner…doesn't exist,” for I've seen isolated pronominal uses of “concerner,” including its tongue-twisting use w/the phrase at issue: [“en ce qui se concerne.”](https://books.google.com/books?id=i6tfvzC6ZO0C&pg=PA127&dq=%22en+ce+qui+se+concerne%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiKr77kxJ7QAhVG34MKHX-fA1IQ6AEIPjAF#v=onepage&q=%22en%20ce%20qui%20se%20concerne%22&f=false)

Comment: Yes, it is. I'd argue that "se concerner" is a degenerated pronominal verb (or, as you say, that there are isolated pronominal uses of it). I answered Aurélien in [another comment](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/22871/en-se-qui-concerne-en-ce-qui-concerne/22873?noredirect=1#comment44168_22872).

Answer (score -1):

The correct expression is "en **ce** qui concerne". The other expression doesn't exist.
Saying "en se qui concerne", would mean the verb is "se concerner", but it doesn't exist in French.

Comment: C'est exact mais il faudrait donner des explications.

Comment: Oui pardon, c'est mon premier post. Cela est-il mieux ?

Comment: Cette expliquation ne fonctionne pas pour "en ce qui regarde", car "se regarder" existe... mais la construction de la phrase serait quand même erronée...

Comment: Sauf que "en ce qui regarde" n'existe pas et je ne vois pas d'autres verbes qui peuvent être utiliser dans la forme "en ce qui" + verbe.

Comment: "[*En ce qui touche*](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/clefsfp/index-eng.html?lang=eng&lettr=indx_catlog_t&page=9LLhMjLNPRis.html)", "*en ce qui a trait à*". As Papa Poule hints to, what about "Il ne se concerne que de l'année 2016" ? "Se concerner" est rare, mais existe.

Comment: Welcome to the site, btw :) Sorry if we sound harsh on you for your first post ^^